# Google Calendar API: Editing a single occurrence of a recurring event

Tags: google-calendar-api

Using the Google Calendar API, how can I edit a single occurrence of a recurring event? (the web interface allows me to do that)

Answer (score 6):

Reading through some of the google forums on this I came across an answer from a google employee:

> What you can also do is to retrieve
>   the events by adding the query
>   parameter 'singleevents=true' to the
>   feed URL. This will expand the
>   recurring events into multiple events.
>   http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters
>
> You will just have to modify the
>   desired events and it will create the
>   exception.
>
> About the "Forbidden g:originalEvent
>   [2010-02-08 06:00:00] does NOT
>   correspond to an instance of the
>   recurring event": this mean that the
>   When object set in the OriginalEvent
>   doesn't match the time of the
>   occurrence of the recurring event.